# Bootstrap mongoose models into BackboneJS

Tags: json, backbone.js, mongoose, express

I've got the following embedded docs Mongoose model defined

```
    var mongoose = require("mongoose");
    module.exports = function(mongoose) {
        var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
            chapters, articles;

        Articles = new Schema({
            identity: Number,
            order: Number,
            quick_title: String,
            full_title: String,
            last_edited: Number,
            contributor: [String],
            content: String,
            video_link: String,
            presentation_link: String,
            question_id: [Number],
            show_in_chapter: Boolean,
            summary_text: String,
            summary_image: String
        });
        chapters = new Schema({
            order: Number,
            title: String,
            articles: [Articles]
        });

        return mongoose.model('chapters', chapters);
    }
```

After getting the entire model database through a .find, I'm currently attempting to bootstrap it into a backboneJS model by using the author recommended method (using EJS templating engine):

```
    var Chapters = Backbone.Collection.extend({});
    chapters = new Chapters( JSON.stringify(<%=chapters%>));
```

I've tried quite a few ways to get it to work, using the above code it will give me the error Unexpected SyntaxError Unexpected Number (in reference to the first title being Chapter 1)

Any ideas on how to turn this Mongoose model into a Backbonejs model? 
Thanks!

UPDATE:

Gotten it to work by using stringify before sending it to the template and then within the template, covering it with parentheses: `chapters = new Chapters("(" + <%-chapters2%> + ")");`

Unfortunately, this does not give me the Backbone collection I want. When I 'console.log(chapters.toJSON());', it just gives me the following

```
[
Object
([object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]): Object
__proto__: Object
]
```

When using the .at method, there's also only one model at (0). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try Unescaped buffering with <%-chapters%> if you do not JSON.stringify on the server

```
chapters = new Chapters(<%- JSON.stringify(chapters) %>);
```

Comment: Comes up with the same error. If I put quotes around the <%-chapters%>, then it comes up with an Unexpected token ILLEGAL error on the first line reading:
chapters = new Chapters( JSON.stringify("Chapter 1 - Something Interesting,{ summary_image: 'http://melindascashsource.files.wordpress.com/2012/04/i-need-money2.jpg',

Comment: Got it to work by using stringify before sending it to the template and then putting it within parentheses. Still can't get it to output to Backbone models correctly.

Comment: sorry, it was on my mind but got it all wrong, the solution is:   `chapters = new Chapters(<%- JSON.stringify(chapters) %>);`

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question after UPDATE, the below works for me, IF you JSON.stringify on the server side

```
var Chapter = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var Chapters = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Chapter
});
var collection = new Chapters(<%-names%>);
console.log(collection.toJSON());
```